# How can I go back to the previous page with flutter_webview on button click?

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I want to build a simple app using `webview_flutter` with no `AppBar`, with a static URL, and just a simple `floatingActionButton` on the bottom of the screen to navigate to the previous page, but I don't know how to do it.

Can someone just give me some guidelines so I can try to make the button do what it is supposed to do?

Here's an image of the app with the button:

[image]

I dunno what to try, but I'm trying to learn, sry about that =D

This is my whole code:
=)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main () {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Something',
    home: AplicativoB2b(),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  ));
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays ([]);
}

class AplicativoB2b extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AplicativoB2bState createState() => _AplicativoB2bState();
}

class _AplicativoB2bState extends State<AplicativoB2b> {

  Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://google.com',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
           _controller.complete(webViewController);
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
               //HELP ME HERE!! =(
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            ),
      // bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(color: Colors.white, child: Container(height: 50.0),),
      // floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it! =D

It might look simple to lots of people haha, but for someone who never touched this kind of stuff before, I'm very proud of my ninja Ctrl C + Ctrl V. Just kidding, I looked at loads of exemples and tried this and it workd, if anyone has any suggestions I'd aprecciate it! =)

Here's what I did:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main () {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Something',
    home: AplicativoB2b(),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  ));
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays ([]);
}

class AplicativoB2b extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AplicativoB2bState createState() => _AplicativoB2bState();
}

class _AplicativoB2bState extends State<AplicativoB2b> {

  Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://google.com',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
           _controller.complete(webViewController);
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: NavigationControls(_controller.future), // <-- added this
      );
  }
}
```

And the class I used for the `floatingActionButton`.

```
class NavigationControls extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavigationControls(this._webViewControllerFuture)
      : assert(_webViewControllerFuture != null);

  final Future<WebViewController> _webViewControllerFuture;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
      future: _webViewControllerFuture,
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> snapshot) {
        final bool webViewReady =
            snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done;
        final WebViewController controller = snapshot.data;
        return FloatingActionButton.extended(
              onPressed: !webViewReady
                  ? null
                  : () => navigate(context, controller, goBack: true),
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              label: Text("Voltar"),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  navigate(BuildContext context, WebViewController controller,
      {bool goBack: false}) async {
    bool canNavigate =
        goBack ? await controller.canGoBack() : await controller.canGoForward();
    if (canNavigate) {
      goBack ? controller.goBack() : controller.goForward();
    } else {
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
            content: Text("Sem histórico anterior")),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

That's basically the whole code. Flutter is cool and easy to lean when you really want it.
Thx to all!

Comment: Could you please explain me why we have to use a Completer instead of calling WebViewControler.goBack() directly?

Comment: I was able to call the controller directly without using Completer.

Answer (score 11):

```
Future<bool> _willPopCallback() async {
    WebViewController webViewController = await _controller.future;
    bool canNavigate = await webViewController.canGoBack();
    if (canNavigate) {
      webViewController.goBack();
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Little explanation to your answer will make it more clear and understandable, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and add description to improve quality of answer.

Answer (score 5):

I did it with different code than the previous answer. I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wo0o0wSkn4k) tutorial to get the webview & the floating button working. From there, it is really easy to give the floating button a back arrow icon and make the webview go back a page when the floating button is clicked.

To make the webview go back a page when the floating button is clicked (put this in its onpressed method):

```
 controller.data.goBack();
```

The icon of the floating button can easily be changed at this line of code:

```
child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back)
```

All of the different buttons can be found here: [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html)

Here is all of my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'App'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: "https://google.com",
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _controller.complete(webViewController);
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
        future: _controller.future,
        builder: (BuildContext context, 
          AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> controller) {
            if (controller.hasData) {
              return FloatingActionButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                onPressed: () {
                  controller.data.goBack();
                });
            }

            return Container();
          }
        ),
    );
  }
}
```